# LibGDX Stage vs SpriteBatch to draw the Game

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx, game-engine, game-physics

I have a big problem with the drawing in LibGDX. First I don´t use every physics or other complicate things in my game. I only draw sprites and put Rectangles at this for Collision Detection. I have 3 Screens in my game: splash, menu and game. So I use a Stage in the splash and menu screen but I don´t really if I use Stage in the game too or I draw with SpriteBatch? The Stage have really pros with Actions but it a little bit more complicate to use Actors. Are there other ways to do this? I don´t want to use World, because its to complicate for the beginning of game developing.
What I want to use for the game?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually you always draw with `SpriteBatch`, as `Stage` uses its own `SpriteBatch`. If you think you could need some of the advantages of `Scene2d`s `Stage`, like `Action`s, `Group`s or other things, you should use `Stage`. In my opinion it is really easy to use. You have your own objects, which extend `Image` or `Actor`, override their `update(delta)` methods, where you check if the `Actor` should move (Keypressed or an event for the AI). Also you should detect collisions there and take care about them. Then, if you are extending `Image` you don't need to care about drawing (but `Image` needs `Drawable`s so you will have some problems with `Animation`s), if you are extending `Actor` override the `draw(SpriteBatch batch)`, where you call `batch.draw(...)`.
Thats it.
A big disadvantage of `Stage` is the sorting. The `Actor`, which is drawn as first is in the background. The last `Actor` overdraws all others and is in foreground. You can sort them by using the z-Index, but it is not really sure.
So you may decide to use your own kind of `Stage` (it is more or less a list, containing all `Actor`s, and when `update`or `draw` is called, it is called for every `Actor` in this list), and add your own sorting there.
It depends on your game design, on your opinion and on your style. Look at some tutorials/examples and decide how you want to create your game.

Comment: Second awesome answer, but much more details, which help me a lot ;)

Comment: I use Scene2D simply so that I can use the `EventListener` with little to no overhead.

Answer (score 16):

You can use either, it depends on what kind of game are you creating. But anyway, **don't create multiple instances of** `SpriteBatch` — instead create only one and pass it to `Stage` constructor, because it's heavy object. (Yes, `Stage` uses a `SpriteBatch` under the hood)
Also, `Stage` may be extremely useful if you need any **on-screen controls** (buttons, joystick, etc), because you can use classes from `scene2d.ui` and don't reinvent the wheel (some wheels are not very easy to reinvent properly)

Comment: I have a question, is doing multiple batch.begin() and batch.end() costly ? I am asking because after you are done with spritebatch, you have to call batch.end() and in the source code of Stage, it calls batch.begin() and batch.end() again.

Comment: @EnesBattal I can't give an exact answer. It is definitely costly, because batch.end() presumably sends the commands to GPU, but in practice it doesn't hurt _too much_ if used 2 times per frame, and in this case it's a necessary evil (otherwise one needs to use more complex abstractions, or do all drawing on lower level)